# My topics-mysql-query-counter does not work

Tags: mysql

I am workin' on this feature for two hours now. There's something I'm doing wrong and I can't get what exactly.

I have, for this example, two tables :

```
 Table 1 : fo_forums
 ID | parent (id) | title

 Table 2 : fo_topics
 ID | parent (id) | title
```

A forum CAN have a parent (which is a forum too), and this parent CAN have a parent (an other forum), but this last one can't have a parent. *(So, we can just have 3 generations of forums)*

A topic HAS a parent, which is a forum.

I am trying to perform one simple thing : **get a list of the forums with the number of topics inside them AND inside their potential children (between 0 and 2 children)**.

I tested many things, the last I did is :

```
SELECT fo.fo_id, 
 (SELECT COUNT(fot_id) FROM fo_topics
    WHERE fot.parent = fo.fo_id OR fot.parent = foc1.fo_id OR fot.parent = foc2.fo_id
 ) as count
FROM fo_forums as fo
 LEFT JOIN fo_forums as foc1 ON foc1.fo_parent = fo.fo_id
 LEFT JOIN fo_forums as foc2 ON foc2.fo_parent = foc1.fo_id
```

With this query, I get some incoherent numbers... I really dont know how to write it.

Plz notice :

- i'm using MySQL
- this is a simplify query (I get other stuff about the forum in the "real query", but with or without this stuff it changes nothing)

Thx for your help.

Answer (score 0):

After a few hours of work (too many hours, tbh), the best thing I could get is those 2 versions : (it's in french, plz don't bother)

```
Version 1:
SELECT DISTINCT fo.fo_id, fo.fo_parent, fo.fo_type, fo.fo_statut, fo.fo_ordre, fo.fo_titre,
    COUNT(DISTINCT fot.fot_id) as nbr_topics, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT fot2.fot_id) as nbr_topics_enfants, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT fop.fop_id) as nbr_posts,
    COUNT(DISTINCT fop2.fop_id) as nbr_posts_enfants,
    fopi.fop_id, fopi.fop_timestamp, fopi.fop_fotid, fopi.fop_uid, u.u_pseudonyme, u.u_avatar, foti.fot_id, foti.fot_titre
FROM fo_forums as fo
    LEFT JOIN fo_forums as foe ON foe.fo_parent = fo.fo_id
    LEFT JOIN fo_forums as fope ON fope.fo_parent = foe.fo_id
    LEFT JOIN fo_topics as fot ON (fot.fot_foid = fo.fo_id)
        LEFT JOIN fo_posts as fop ON fop.fop_fotid = fot.fot_id
    LEFT JOIN fo_topics as fot2 ON (fot2.fot_foid = foe.fo_id OR fot2.fot_foid = fope.fo_id)
        LEFT JOIN  fo_posts as fop2 ON fop2.fop_fotid = fot2.fot_id
    LEFT JOIN fo_posts as fopi ON fopi.fop_id = (SELECT MAX(fot_derniermsg) FROM fo_topics WHERE (fot_foid = fo.fo_id))
        LEFT JOIN fo_topics as foti ON foti.fot_id = fopi.fop_fotid
        LEFT JOIN u_individus as u ON u.u_id = fopi.fop_uid
GROUP BY fo.fo_id
```

And :

```
Version 2
SELECT DISTINCT fo.fo_id, fo.fo_parent, fo.fo_type, fo.fo_statut, fo.fo_ordre, fo.fo_titre,
    (SELECT COUNT(fot.fot_id) FROM fo_topics as fot WHERE fot.fot_foid = fo.fo_id) as nbr_topics,
    (SELECT COUNT( fot.fot_id) FROM fo_topics as fot 
        LEFT JOIN fo_forums as foe ON foe.fo_id IS NOT NULL 
        LEFT JOIN fo_forums as fope ON fope.fo_parent = foe.fo_id 
    WHERE ( (foe.fo_parent = fo.fo_id) AND (fot.fot_foid = foe.fo_id OR fot.fot_foid = fope.fo_id))
    ) as nbr_topics_enfants,
    (SELECT COUNT(fop.fop_id) FROM fo_posts as fop JOIN fo_topics as fot ON fot.fot_id = fop.fop_fotid WHERE fot.fot_foid = fo.fo_id) as nbr_posts,
    (SELECT COUNT( fop.fop_id) FROM fo_topics as fot 
        LEFT JOIN fo_forums as foe ON foe.fo_id IS NOT NULL 
        LEFT JOIN fo_forums as fope ON fope.fo_parent = foe.fo_id
        LEFT JOIN fo_posts as fop ON fop.fop_fotid = fot.fot_id
    WHERE ( (foe.fo_parent = fo.fo_id) AND (fot.fot_foid = foe.fo_id OR fot.fot_foid = fope.fo_id))
    ) as nbr_posts_enfants,
    fopi.fop_id, fopi.fop_timestamp, fopi.fop_fotid, fopi.fop_uid, u.u_pseudonyme, u.u_avatar, foti.fot_id, foti.fot_titre
FROM fo_forums as fo
    LEFT JOIN fo_posts as fopi ON fopi.fop_id = (SELECT MAX(fot_derniermsg) FROM fo_topics WHERE (fot_foid = fo.fo_id))
        LEFT JOIN fo_topics as foti ON foti.fot_id = fopi.fop_fotid
        LEFT JOIN u_individus as u ON u.u_id = fopi.fop_uid
```

With this, I can get :

- all the basics informations of the forum (title, status...)
- the number of topics directly linked to the forum
- the number of topics linked to the forum's children (meaning : other forums)
- the number of posts in the topics of the forum
- the number of posts in the topics of the forum's children
- the informations (id, date and user's infos) of the last post/topics in the forum

It's a little messy, at least in my opinion, and I'm pretty sure there's a nicer way and a better-in-performance way to do that, but I can't figure out how.

Pretty astonishing, for me at least, the second version is *faster* than the first one.

If someone has an idea to improive this, I'm opened to suggestion. In the meantime, it will be my function !